Compile Failed of gcc 13.2.0 of lfs version 12.1
When i fellow the command of the lfs book 12.1 i chapter 5  to compile gcc 13.2.0 , i got the error.
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 13.2.0 (GCC) 
configure:3560: $? = 0
configure:3549: /mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/lfs/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/mnt/lfs/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /mnt/lfs/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/include -isystem /mnt/lfs/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/sys-include    -V >&5
xgcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-V'
xgcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3560: $? = 1
configure:3549: /mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/lfs/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/mnt/lfs/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /mnt/lfs/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/include -isystem /mnt/lfs/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/sys-include    -qversion >&5
xgcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
xgcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3560: $? = 1
configure:3576: /mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/lfs/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/mnt/lfs/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /mnt/lfs/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/include -isystem /mnt/lfs/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/sys-include    -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c  >&5
In file included from conftest.c:9:
/usr/include/stdio.h:27:10: fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory
   27 | #include <bits/libc-header-start.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
configure:3579: $? = 1
configure:3792: checking for suffix of object files
configure:3814: /mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build/./gcc/ -B/mnt/lfs/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/mnt/lfs/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /mnt/lfs/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/include -isystem /mnt/lfs/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/sys-include    -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build/./gcc/as: 114: exec: --64: not found
configure:3818: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Runtime Library"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libgcc"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Runtime Library 1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/libgcc/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3832: error: in `/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-13.2.0/build/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/libgcc':
configure:3834: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details

the configure options is below as the book recommend.
../configure --target=$LFS_TGT --prefix=$LFS/tools --with-glibc-version=2.39 --with-sysroot=$LFS --with-newlib --without-headers --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-multilib --disable-threads --disable-libgomp --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --disable-libvtv --disable-libstdcxx --enable-languages=c,c++

my host information is Debian 12 and the gcc version of host is 12.
#uname -r
Linux debian-ms 6.1.0-22-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.94-1 (2024-06-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux

#gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 12.2.0-14' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-12/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-12 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-12-bTRWOB/gcc-12-12.2.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-12-bTRWOB/gcc-12-12.2.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --enable-offload-defaulted --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 12.2.0 (Debian 12.2.0-14) 


And i also link the /usr/include of lfs root path to the host system /usr/include , and i could find the missing file in /usr/include/ of lfs root path.
Is there is something need to be set?
Thanks for help.

And i also link the /usr/include of lfs root path to the host system /usr/include , and i could find the missing file in /usr/include/ of lfs root path. I'm not sure that's how you compile LFS.

i have compiled before , the logs shows can not find stduio.sh . so i exec the command ' ln -sv $LFS/usr/include  /usr/include ' , then i try again . the  error message change to  the descrption.
